# OMXplayer: scale strange rtsp stream

Tags: omxplayer, rtsp

I'm trying to get omxplayer to play an h.264 encoded stream via rtsp from a crappy IPcam. No matter what resolution i set up on the cam, the resolution reported by various players is always 2048x1536. On OMX the video doesn't show up (I suppose it's because the FB is smaller)

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://<the_cam_address>':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP/RTP stream from Network Video Server
    comment         : mpeg4
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.435444, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc), 2048x1536, 18 fps, 18 tbr, 90k tbn, 36 tbc
```

Is there any way I can force a rescale of the input to the actual resolution set up on the cam?